# sort multidimensional array on first number

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

here is my array for example:

```
25 test1, 50 test 50, 10 item ten,100 test100 hi,75 seventy five ok, alpha menu item, bravo ok
```

I trying this function I found here:

```
function arraySort(pArray) {
    pArray.sort(
        function(a,b) {
            var len=a.length;
            for (var i=0;i<len;i++) {
                if (a[i]>b[i]) return 1;
                else if (a[i]<b[i]) return -1;
            }          
            return 0;
        }
    );
}
```

But not getting sort right somehow. Simply desire to sort multidimensional array on first item with is a number only. Well could be a character i guess and if so put at end.

Thank you for great help here.

Mike

Comment: so need to sort the array based on number at the beginning of the string I believe if it is a number.

Comment: myArray = [25 test1, 50 test 50, 10 item ten,100 test100 hi,75 seventy five ok, alpha menu item, bravo ok];

Comment: What about making a 2D array where first column is the number, then sort on that numerically, then put together for output, output is number and string then a \n for carriage return :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var yourArray = ['25 test1', '50 test 50', '10 item ten', '100 test100 hi', '75 seventy five ok', 'alpha menu item', 'bravo ok'];

function arraySort(pArray) {
    return pArray.sort(function(a, b) {
        var an = parseInt(a), bn = parseInt(b);
        return an > bn  || isNaN(bn) ? -1 : bn > an || isNaN(an) ? 1 : 0;
    });
}

// now call arraySort
var sortedArray = arraySort( yourArray );
```

Comment: sorts but 100 to 10 so descending, I desire smallest number first ! humm

Answer (score 0):

This should work: http://jsfiddle.net/xqhtf2z4/

```
function arraySort(pArray) {
    pArray.sort(
        function(a,b) {
            if ((isNaN(a[0]) && isNaN(b[0])) || (!isNaN(a[0]) && !isNaN(b[0]))) {
                if (a[0] > b[0]) {
                    return 1;
                }
                else if (a[0] < b[0]) {
                    return -1;
                }
                else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            else {
                if (isNaN(a[0])) {
                    return 1;
                }
                else { // isNaN(b[0]) == true
                    return -1;
                }
            }       
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: so need to sort the array based on number at the beginning of the string I believe if it is a number, if it a alpha just add to end of array. thank you.

Comment: ok, after the sort the Array is undefined. do we need a return pArray in the code?  I am learning this all.

Comment: I added and now returns array, though it is not sorted right for some reason.

Comment: In the jsfiddle I linked, it displays the first element's first element value, and then the last element's first element value. Nothing should be undefined; check how I wrote the fiddle.

Comment: here is output:
Debug: 2566 before sort: 10 test, 11 test me, 25 show me,100 hundred here,Blue man,33 test 30

Debug: 2569 after sort: 11 test me, 25 show me,10 test,100 hundred here,33 test 30,Blue man

Comment: I used your values and still got it to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/xqhtf2z4/1/

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that your array isn't defined correctly. Look at how I did it in the fiddle links.

Comment: ok Cody appreciate it, Martin above code got it perfectly after I flipped the <>. I do not really understand that return line of his code at all! I am learning javascript, but it worked!!!! your code might also.

Comment: I am the only one here that actually used a multi-dimensional array pursuant to your question, and my code works fine will all test data. Every one else has used a 1-dimensional array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = ["bravo ok", "alpha menu item", "25 test1", "50 test 50", "10 item ten","100 test100 hi","75 seventy five ok"];
arr.sort(function(a,b){return a.localeCompare(b);})
```

output is:

```
["10 item ten", "100 test100 hi", "25 test1", "50 test 50", "75 seventy five ok", "alpha menu item", "bravo ok"]
```

Working fine for me.

Comment: so need to sort the array based on number at the beginning of the string I believe if it is a number, if it a alpha just add to end of array. thank you.

Comment: hi Vikas it seems it did not work I can try it again.  appreciate the help.  that array is strings, where first item in string is a number. understand, not sure why so hard to do. :) hummm thanks

Comment: here is output:
Debug: 2566 before sort: 10 test, 11 test me, 25 show me,100 hundred here,Blue man,33 test of this

Debug: 2569 after sort: 11 test me, 25 show me,10 test,100 hundred here,33 test of this,Blue man